# How to calculate age in query?Age search

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a table divided by year months and day
[image]

How do I calculate age to use it in an input?
The code that invokes the input is..

```
if(isset($keyage)){


$keyag = "AND bday_month LIKE '".$keyage."'";




}
```

But the research is based only on the month, how can I look through age-
Thank you

Comment: Store dates as a single enitity

Comment: Combine the values, then cast as a date to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to compute your age according to your sample data:

```
select case when m_now>m_table then age 
            when m_now=m_table THEN
                 case when d_now=d_table then age ELSE
                       case when d_now<=d_table then age-1 else age end

       end
ELSE age -1 END as age from

(select day(date(now()))d_now,day(date(CONCAT_WS('-',bday_year,bday_month,bday_day))) d_table,
month(date(now()))m_now, month(date(CONCAT_WS('-',bday_year,bday_month,bday_day)))m_table,
year(date(now()))-year(date(CONCAT_WS('-',bday_year,bday_month,bday_day))) age from
(Select 4 bday_month, 1 as bday_day , 1981 bday_year) as a) as a
```